# Proving a not-so-clear equality!

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I am working through a paper on Random Walks in Random Environments at the moment (Solomon 1975), the introductory paper to the topic. I have come rather unstuck at proving an equality.

Prove 
$$e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-[(\theta+1)^2 -4\theta e^{-2u}]^{\frac{1}{2}}) = \frac{2\theta}{\theta - 1} \cdot u + O(u^2)$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Link to the paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996444 
It's on page 12!

Comment: Rather stuck, you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $\theta>1$? (Otherwise, it is not the case, as we will see during the derivation.)

Use the Taylor expansions around $0$:
\begin{align}
e^u &= 1+u+O(u^2) \tag{1}\\
e^{-2u} &= 1-2u+O(u^2)\tag{2}\\
\sqrt{1+u} &= 1+\frac{u}{2}+O(u^2)\tag{3}
\end{align}
so that your LHS becomes, when $u\to 0$,
\begin{align}
\textrm{LHS} &=
e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-\sqrt{(\theta+1)^2 -4\theta (1-2u+O(u^2))}) \tag{From (2)}\\
&= e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-\sqrt{1+\theta^2-2\theta +8\theta u+O(u^2)}) \\
&= e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-\sqrt{(\theta-1)^2 +8\theta u+O(u^2)}) \\
&= e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-\lvert \theta-1\rvert\sqrt{1 +\frac{8\theta}{(\theta-1)^2} u+O(u^2)}) \\
&= e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1-\lvert \theta-1\rvert\left(1 +\frac{4\theta}{(\theta-1)^2} u+O(u^2)\right)) \tag{From (3)}\\ 
&= e^u - \frac{e^u}{2}(\theta +1- (\theta-1) -\frac{4\theta}{\theta-1} u+O(u^2)) \tag{As $\theta > 1$}\\ 
&= e^u - e^u(1 -\frac{2\theta}{\theta-1} u+O(u^2))\\
&= e^u(\frac{2\theta}{\theta-1} u+O(u^2))\\
&= (1-u+O(u^2))\left(\frac{2\theta}{\theta-1} u+O(u^2)\right)\tag{From (1)}\\
&= \frac{2\theta}{\theta-1} u+O(u^2)
\end{align}
as claimed.

*Note that if $\theta\in(0,1)$, this no longer holds (the step where we used $\lvert \theta-1\rvert = \theta-1$ no longer holds), and we would get instead that the LHS is $1-\theta+O(u)$.*

Comment: Yes you are right $\theta$ is larger than 1. That helps me so much thank you very much for your help! I didn't think to use a taylor expansion of (1+u) which obviously was very necessary! Can't thank you enough really is vital to what I am doing :)

Comment: You're welcome!